# Showing JPA results on p:dataTable

Tags: jsf, jpa, primefaces, datatable

I have an entity for getting book list from DB. So I created a List that type MyEntity.When I click to the button I want to fill the  If I call method head of the xhtml ,  Here is my codes

```
< p:commandButton value="Tüm Kitaplar" actionListener="#{oduncKitapVerBean.tumListeyiDoldur}"/>

< p:dataTable id="kitapliste" var="kl" rowKey="#{kl.kitapID}"
                                 value="#{oduncKitapVerBean.entityList}" 
                                 paginator="true" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"
                                 paginatorPosition="bottom"
                                 selection="#{oduncKitapVerBean.selectedEntity}"
                                 selectionMode="single">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Kitap Listesi"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <p:column headerText="Kitap Adı" filterBy="#{kl.kitapad}" sortBy="#{kl.kitapad}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                            <h:outputText value="#{kl.kitapad}"/>
                        </p:column>
 </p:dataTable>
```

Here is my ManagedBean method,

```
public void tumListeyiDoldur() {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("KutuphaneOtomasyonuPU");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    try {
        entityList = em.createNamedQuery("tumkitaplarigetir").getResultList();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have controlled on debug mode. entityList is filling from query. But why dataTable is not fulling?

Comment: `entityList` with getter ?

Comment: maybe you should add update="kitapliste" to your cammand button. what is your bean scope? and are you trying to use Ajax or you are rendering page again after button press?

Comment: It is viwscope and I don't try using ajax

Comment: yes. I use entityList with getter.